# Azure Policies at Subscription Level not working

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

We assigned "Allowed Locations" built in policy at Subscription Level (with USEAST allowed) and DENY effect. Now after that I tried to create a Resource Group in a different location (Europe)and I am able to create the resource group. Ideally I should not be able to create a RG since allowed location is only EASTUS and I am trying to create in Europe.

Is this a bug or something I am missing out? I have ensured the policy is applied on Subscription level (Scope).

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: It may take a few minutes for the rule to take effect. Please wait and see if it can work later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mode element determines which resource types are evaluated for a policy definition."Indexed" mode  should be used when creating policies that enforce tags or locations. Policy definitions that enforce location or tags on a resource group or subscription should set mode to all and specifically target the Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups or Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions type.

Reference article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#mode

Comment: Perfect @swathiDhanwada-MSFT this was the case :). I had mode set to Indexed and that was the reason the policy was not getting applied to RG. Post changing the mode to "all" this worked and now the policy is in effect on RG. thank you for your help!